# Getting rid of BOM between SAS and R

Tags: r, sas, byte-order-mark

I used SAS to save a tab-delimited text file with `utf8` encoding on a windows machine.  Then I tried to open this in R:

```
read.table(myfile, header =TRUE, sep = "\t")
```

To my surprise, the data was totally messed up, but only in a sneaky way.  Number values changed randomly, but the overall layout looked normal, so it took me a while to notice the problem, which I'm assuming now is the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

This is not a new issue of course; they address it briefly [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-data.html), and recommend using

```
read.table(myfile, fileEncoding = "UTF-8", header =TRUE, sep = "\t")
```

However, this made no improvement!  My only solution was to suppress the header, with or without the `fileEncoding` argument:

```
read.table(myfile, fileEncoding = "UTF-8", header =FALSE, sep = "\t")
read.table(myfile, header =FALSE, sep = "\t")
```

In either case, I have to do some funny business to replace the column names with the first row, but only after I remove some version of the BOM that appears at the beginning of the first column name (`<U+FEFF>` if I use `fileEncoding` and 
`ï»¿` if I don't use `fileEncoding`).

Isn't there a simple way to just remove the BOM and use `read.table` without any special arguments?

**Update for @Joe:**
The SAS that I used:

```
FILENAME myfile 'C:\Documents ... file.txt'  encoding="utf-8";
proc export data=lib.sastable
  outfile=myfile
  dbms=tab  replace;
  putnames=yes;
run;
```

**Update on further weirdness:**  Using `fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM"` as @Joe suggested in his solution below seems to remove the BOM.  **However**, it did not fix my original motivating problem, which is corruption in the data; the header row is fine, but weirdly the last few digits of the first column of numbers gets messed up.  I'll give Joe credit for his answer -- maybe my problem is not actually a BOM issue?

**Hack solution:**  Use `fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM"` AND also include the argument `colClasses = "character"`.  No idea why this works to fix the data corruption issue -- could be the topic of a future question.

Comment: How are you writing out the file in SAS?

Comment: @Joe, see update on question.

Comment: I assume UTF-8 is nonnegotiable, and is _not_ the encoding of your SAS session?

Comment: @Joe, great point.  The choice of encoding is entirely negotiable.  In fact I was trying to figure out which encoding is best for importing things to R, but failed.  You have a recommendation?  (I'm not sure how to check the encoding "of my SAS session", although at least there was one reference to "wlatin1")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your link, it looks like it works for me with:

```
read.table('c:\\temp\\testfile.txt',fileEncoding='UTF-8-BOM',header=TRUE,sep='\t')
```

note the -BOM in the file encoding.

This is in [2.1 Variations on read.table](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-data.html#Variations-on-read_002etable) in the r documentation.  Under 12 Encoding, see "Under UNIX you might need...", which apparently applies even on Windows now (for me, at least).

Comment: Surprised to see that this works on Windows, despite the documentation!

Answer (score 0):

or you can use the sas system option `options=NOBOMFILE` the write a uft-8 file without the BOM.