# Sas Export procedure returning an unreadable csv

Tags: r, sas

I am writing a macro to run a csv and there are 56 csv files being created in the macro, Out of the 56 when i try to open one of them in notepad, it opens and the values are all japanes looking

```
%let loca=/bayer/aparajith.chandran/Input;
%macro state_separate();
%do i = 1 %to &cnt_state.;
%let temp= %scan(&state.,&i.);
    data test1.onco_&temp.;
    set test.onco_LG_input;
    if state ne "&temp." then delete;
    run;
    proc export data=test1.onco_&temp.
    outfile="&loca./onco_&temp..csv"
    replace
    dbms=csv;
    delimiter=",";
%end;   

%mend;
```

[image: This is the output I get]

What is the reason for this???

The file opens properly in excel, but when i try to read the file in R, it gives me warnings and deletes rows of data.

Why is this??

Comment: Try using a better editor, e.g. Notepad++. You can change encodings there. Does the problem persist?

Comment: It is an automated process, so as the files are made in SAS, they are read by R. Is there ayway, it can be done using the SAS code itself??

Comment: What is it? What do you need R to do? I suggest looking at the encoding=option on your datastep as well and explicitly set that to UTF8.

Comment: Basically i divide my data state wise and these 56 files are processed in R, so i don't want any manual intervention. I cant get rid of this error and every time i have to open and save this particular file.

Comment: Any workaround which has been found for this??

Comment: What happens if you set the NOBOMFILE option before writing the files in SAS?  https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Write-a-file-in-UTF-8-without-BOM/td-p/561069

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read through this error and found out that, this is a windows error,It's called "Bush Hid the facts", there are no current workarounds for this as of yet, so I dont know how to correct this

Answer (score 1):

I guess this could be due to what character set is used to encode the csv-file in the proc export-statement, and that Notepad assumes the character set is utf-8.

Using a filename statement where you specify the encoding seems like a viable solution, as suggested in this post:
[Getting rid of BOM between SAS and R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23351020/getting-rid-of-bom-between-sas-and-r)

```
FILENAME myfile 'C:\Documents ... file.txt'  encoding="utf-8";
proc export data=lib.sastable
outfile=myfile
dbms=tab  replace;
putnames=yes;
run;
```

Comment: It opens in Excel, but when i try to import the file in R, it gives me an error

Comment: Is there a workaround which I can include in my code to take care of this??

Comment: I read through this error and found out that, this is a windows error,It's called "Bush Hid the facts", there are no current workarounds for this as of yet, so I dont know how to correct this